# date time comparisons in hive sql

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql

in hive sql I have the following field as date time

```
date_time
2017-01-01 12:00:00 

min_date
2017-02-01 12:00:00
```

can I compare both fields as `date_time > min_date`

in my sql query?

how do we compare date time in hive sql?

both timestamp types

Comment: What is the datatype of  these 2 columns? TIMESTAMP or Varchar?

Comment: both timestamp types

Answer (score 1):

You can compare timestamps or strings if they are in sort-able format like this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.f...]`

Demo:

```
hive> select cast('2017-01-01 12:00:00' as timestamp)>cast('2017-02-01 12:00:00' as timestamp);
OK
false
Time taken: 0.13 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Example with strings:

```
hive> select '2017-01-01 12:00:00'>'2017-02-01 12:00:00';
OK
false
Time taken: 1.053 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```